# Finding The Max Value from Density Function (Kernel Estimator) in Java

Tags: java, weka

I'm using the KernelEstimator class ([KernelEstimator.java](https://github.com/rlichtenwalter/LPmade/blob/master/weka/src/weka/estimators/KernelEstimator.java)) from the Weka library.

I want to find the max value in my density function, that is, the value with the highest density. I have been looking at the mean-shift algorithm ([Mean-shift wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift)) but I don't know how to implement it with the methods I have available from the KernelEstimator class.

*Specifically:* How can I implement the mean-shift algorithm in Java (or other algorithms that find the max value), preferable using what I have available from the KernelEstimator class?

If there are better libraries that can solve my problem other than the Weka library, please let me know.

Thanks.